# Monty Hall: What's wrong with my approach

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, monty-hall

Let us say we have n boxes, and one car.

The probability that one of them might have a car = p

and each box is equally likely to have a car, therefore the change that a single box has car = p/n

Now let us consider the chance that box 1 has car, given other boxes don't have car

P(Box 1 contains car | other n-1 boxes don't contain car)

$$=\frac{P(Box\space1\space contains\space car \cap other\space n-1\space boxes\space don't\space contain\space car)}{P(other\space n-1\space boxes\space don't\space contain\space car)}$$

$$=\frac{P(Box\space1\space contains\space car)}{P(other\space n-1\space boxes\space don't\space contain\space car)}$$

$$=\frac{\frac{p}{n}}{ \left( 1 - \frac{p}{n} \right)^{(n-1)} }$$ [1]

But if we apply this result to classical monty hall problem where we have 3 boxes. Let us say contestant chose box 1.

Other two boxes have p = 2/3 to have car, n  = 2,

each box will have probability of p/n = $\frac{2/3}{2} = 1/3$, of having a car

If monty opens up say box 3(which doesn't have car),

the probability of box 2 having car

$$=\frac{\frac{p}{n}}{ \left( 1 - \frac{p}{n} \right)^{(n-1)} }$$

here p = 2/3

n = 2
$$=\frac{\frac{2/3}{2}}{ \left( 1 - \frac{2/3}{2} \right)^{(2-1)} }$$
$$= 1/2$$

which is not the correct answer. **I have done something wrong and [1] is not valid result.**

**What is wrong with it?**

PS: I know how to solve monty hall problem using other approach. I want to know what is wrong with this approach?

Comment: The events [box 2 has no car], [box 3 has no car], etc. are not independent (at most one of them is false, since there is only one car). Hence the probability of [other n-1 boxes don't have a car] is not the product of probabilities.

Comment: @D.Thomine Thanks. So in that case the probability that box 2,3,...n don't have car = $\Pi_{i=0}^{n-2}(1 - \frac{p}{n-i}) $ Is my calculation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your are not **actually** computing the Monty Hall Problem. You are computing the probability:
$$
P(\text{box 2}\mid\text{not box 3})=\frac12
$$
Whereas the Monty Hall Problem is concerned with the probability:
$$
P(\text{box 2 OR box 3}\mid\text{(not box 3) OR (not box 2)})=\frac23
$$

---

To comment on your derivation, by $n$ you do not mean the total number of boxes since otherwise specifying that $n-1$ boxes do not contain a car would be redundant. This was unclear when I read it at first.

Instead suppose we have $N>n$ boxes in total. Then you are asking:

> What is the probability that the car is found in the first of the $n<N$ boxes given that it is NOT found in the other $(n-1)$ boxes.

To be clear, this entails the possibility that the car may in fact be in one of the remaining $N-n$ boxes.

---

Then most of your derivation is correct, except for your denominator. It considers  the $(n-1)$ boxes as $(n-1)$ independent trials, which it is not. We are only considering a single trial here. Rather the denominator should be:
$$
P(\text{not the other $n-1$ boxes})=1-(n-1)\cdot\tfrac pn
$$

Comment: "Whereas the Monty Hall Problem is concerned with the probability:
$$
P(\text{box 2 OR box 3}\mid\text{(not box 3) OR (not box 2)})=\frac23
$$"

Could your please elaborate on this a bit. I am not able to wrap my head around this formulation.

Comment: Also, Monty knows car is in which box, how is that knowledge factored in this formulation?

Comment: @q126y: In the classical problem, the contestant has (WLOG) chosen box 1. Then one of the other boxes is opened revealing either "not box 2" OR "not box 3". Now we are asked to evaluate the probability that the contestant should change their mind (away from box 1). This gives us two scenarios: $$P(\text{box 2}\mid\text{not box 3})$$ OR $$P(\text{box 3}\mid\text{not box 2})$$, which is what I tried to combine into the compressed expression: $$P(\text{box 2 OR box 3}\mid\text{(not box 3) OR (not box 2)})=\frac23$$

Comment: @q126y: The knowledge Monty holds about the car is factored in *exactly* by stating the two possibilities "not box 2" OR "not box 3". He would never reveal a box containing the car, so if box 2 contains the car he would be forced to opt for the "not box 3"-condition.

Comment: this is some new insight into the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Off topic, how do I think intuitively the probability problems? Do you have any suggestion for books or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your definition of $p$ is rather vague.
 Try something in the lines of: Assuming there are $n$ boxes, each box has the probability of containing the car equal to $p = \frac{1}{n}$.
Now, the probability you propose $$P(\text{Box 1 contains car} | \text{other n-1 boxes don't contain car}) = 1$$
since the statement "Box 1 contains car" is equivalent to "other n-1 boxes don't contain car" because there is only 1 car.
The probability you are looking for is
$$P(\text{Box 1 contains car} | \text{1 other box don't contain car}).$$
Other than that, I think you're on the right track.